# Having an EU working holiday visa and a volunteer visa at the same time?

Tags: visa, germany, working-holiday-visas

I currently have a valid German Working holiday visa. Is it possible to apply for, and receive, a volunteer visa to Hungary at the same time (application for residence permit for the purpose of volunteering)?

I am an Australian.

Comment: The Hungarian visa is one that arises under national rules, so your answer is yes.

Comment: @GayotFow so is the German visa, isn't it?

Comment: @phoog yes, but it's irrelevant in the situation the OP described. Perhaps it's helpful in establishing the OP as a bona fide applicant, but now it's been migrated.